# Finding and extracting words that include a punctuation expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, nlp

I'am stuck trying to extract, from a big text (around 17000 documents), words that contain punctuation expressions. For example

```
"...urine bag tubing and the vent jutting above the summit also strapped with the
 white plaster tapeFigure 2), \n\nc(A<sc>IMS AND</sc> O<sc>BJECTIVES</sc>, The 
 aim of this study is to ... c(M<sc>ATERIALS AND</sc> M<sc>ETHODS</sc>, A 
 cross-sectional study with a ... surgeries.n), \n\nc(PATIENTS & METHODS, This 
 prospective double blind,...[95] c(c(Introduction, Silicosis is a fibrotic"
```

I would like to extract words like the following:

```
 [1] c(A<sc>IMS AND</sc> M<sc>ETHODS</sc>
 [2] c(M<sc>ATERIALS AND</sc> M<sc>ETHODS</sc>
 [3] c(PATIENTS & METHODS,
 [4] c(c(Introduction
```

but not for example words like "cross-sectional", or "2013.", or "2)", or "(inability". This is the first step, my idea is to be able to get to this:

```
"...urine bag tubing and the vent jutting above the summit also strapped with the
 white plaster tapeFigure 2), \n\n AIMS AND OBJECTIVES, The aim of this 
 study is to ... MATERIALS AND METHODS, A cross-sectional study with a ...
 surgeries.n), \n\n PATIENTS AND METHODS, This prospective double blind,...
 [95] Introduction Silicosis is a fibrotic"
```

As a way to extract these words and not grabbing any words that include punctuation (like "surgeries.n)"), I have seen that they always start or include "c(" expression. But had some trouble with the regex:

```
grep("c(", test)
    Error en grep("c(", test) : 
    invalid regular expression 'c(', reason 'Missing ')''
```

also tried with:

```
grep("c\\(", test, value = T)
```

But returns the whole text file. Have also use str_match from the dap package but I don't seem to get the correct pattern (regex) code right. Have any recommendation?

Comment: On your last line of example, there `c(c(Introduction, ...` how should it be treated ?

Comment: I've a hard time to understand what you expect exactly, is the second block of text your expected output  or just a step toward the expected output and you didn't show it ?

Comment: Hi @Tensibai , sorry what I meant is that the second text is my final goal with many steps in between. So for now been able to extract the words I posted is a great step towards that goal. Thank you very much for your concern!

Comment: Fabian, if an answer fit your need, think about accepting it (the check mark). You'll earn reputation point and it marks the question as being answered so other looking at the question list in a tag know it's answered (it helps filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem (I'm unsure your second text is expected output or just a step) I would go with gsub like this:

```
gsub("(c\\(|<\\/?sc>)","",text)
```

The regex (first parameter) will match `c(` or `<sc>` or `</sc>` and replace them with nothing, thus cleaning the text as you expect (again, if I understood correctly your expectation).

more on the regex involved:

- `(|)` is the structure to OR condition
- `c\\(` will match literally `c(` anywhere in the text
- `<\\/?sc>` will match `<sc>` or `</sc>` as the `?` after the `/` mean it can be there 0 or 1 time, so it's optionnal.
- The double `\\` are there so after R interpreter has removed the first backslash there's still a backslash to tell the regex interpreter we want to match a litteral `(` and a litteral `/`

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you very much @Tensibai ! Its a perfect step towards the final goal (second text). –

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
text <- "...urine bag tubing and the vent jutting above the summit also strapped with the white plaster tapeFigure 2), \n\nc(A<sc>IMS AND</sc> O<sc>BJECTIVES</sc>, The aim of this study is to ... c(M<sc>ATERIALS AND</sc> M<sc>ETHODS</sc>, A cross-sectional study with a ... surgeries.n), \n\nc(PATIENTS & METHODS, This prospective double blind,...[95] c(c(Introduction, Silicosis is a fibroticf"

require(stringr)
words <- str_split(text, " ")
words[[1]][grepl("c\\(", words[[1]])]
## [1] "\n\nc(A<sc>IMS"    "c(M<sc>ATERIALS"   "\n\nc(PATIENTS"    "c(c(Introduction,"
```

Comment: This approach excludes words/tokens like "...urine" and "blind,...[95]", which are his the desired remaining paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Stereo, your code help me greatly to identify the words in the document that have c( expression. With this I have an idea of what types of words need to be corrected.